# The model backing the 'DMSContext' context has changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm receiving the following error when running my mvc 4 app.

The model backing the 'DMSContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

I am running my app against an existing database and do no want to recreate the db each time the model changes.

I've found plenty of answers on google, but none have worked.

Specifically, I've tried adding the following to my global.asax:

```
Database.SetInitializer<DMSContext>(null);
```

and

```
Database.SetInitializer<DMSContext<Contact>>(null);
```

in the above, DMSContext is the DbContext. Contact is the Model where the change causing the error originates.

I've also tried adding the following to my context class:

```
public DMSContext() : base()
          {
             Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
          }
```

Most of the direction I've followed is from this page, but no luck.

[The model backing the <Database> context has changed since the database was created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600175/the-model-backing-the-database-context-has-changed-since-the-database-was-crea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with `Entity Framework Code First`, its recommended that you enable migrations in your application. To do so, [see this link](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model).

Now every time you change something in your code (Mostly Entities), just build and then run `Update-Database -Force` in your `Package Manager Console`.

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: This worked, BUT why do I need to run Update-Database? Is this actually effecting the live db? I definitely do not want it to.

I had already enabled migrations useing this guide - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx but was avoiding the update database part.

Comment: @EthanPelton With `ef Code-First` a slight change in your model, requires that you update your database. Models always has to stay current with your database. `Update-Database -Force` makes that possible.

Comment: @EthanPelton yes, change in your `Model` affects your `Live Database` Thats the beauty of Code First, you only do the changes in one place and rarely have to touch the database itself.

Comment: The light bulb just turned on. I was trying to manually update the db and not understanding why I then needed to run the update. I didn't understand that EF was meant to maintain the db at all. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @EthanPelton Glad to help, you should watch Scott Allen's videos, i learn alot from there. http://pluralsight.com/training/Authors/Details/scott-allen

Answer (score 2):

Although you don't use migrations try to create one, do not run it, but you'll be able to see the differences with the database.

Comment: Very useful, I forgot I had added another field in the model -- this pointed me exactly where I needed to look.

Answer (score 2):

Check the name of the class, which inherits the DbContext. It's name have to be the same as the name of the connectionString in Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TheSameNameAsYourDbContextClass" providerName="" connectionString="" />
  </connectionStrings>
```