# Code First Migration failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-6

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/03/ef-4-3-migrations-and-existing-database/)

And then did

```
Update-Database -Force -Verbose
```

It showed that it upgraded the table.
However an error is shown:

```
The model backing the 'DbConnection' context has changed 
since the database was created.
Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database
(http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
```

I also tried

```
Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName MvcApplication6.Models.DbConnection
```

However it says:

```
Migrations have already been enabled in project 'MvcApplication6'. 
To overwrite the existing migrations configuration, use the -Force parameter.
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600175/the-model-backing-the-database-context-has-changed-since-the-database-was-crea).

```
Database.SetInitializer<DbConnection>(null);
```