# CodeFirst Model - cant generate dataBase

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'll try to use CodeFirst model for creating dataBase.

Prepare code like below (from [online tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj572366)). Code is exactly like in tutorial:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (BlogContext db = new BlogContext())
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog:");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();

            var blog = new Blog { Name = name };
            Database.SetInitializer<BlogContext>(null);
            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var query = from b in db.Blogs
                        orderby b.Name
                        select b;

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }

        }
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }

}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

As result - got exception

[image]

Solution for this exception found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6214040/2012219). Now it's ok, work and show me saved data, but in my Sql Server Object explorer i can't see any database or table.

[image]

Any suggestion why? Wnat i must to do for repairing this?

---

Edit

[image]

So, as was mentioned by @Sergiy Berezovskiy - i try to check dataBase and add manually dataConnection for displaying just created dataBase.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two problems:

- You are looking on wrong database. Without connection string specified Entity Framework will create database on local SQLEXPRESS server with name equal to context name - *SomeNamespace.BlogContext* in your case.
- You changed model after you created database. That's why you see that error. Either use [Code First Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) to update existing database, or use [`DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) database initializer to re-create database.

Comment: Regarding first point - please see Edit (add additional screen), also according to tutorial i don't create any connection string, i check .config file - no connection string there. Do I must to add it manually for proper work? Regarding second point - i just read about migration and add all required changes. But the main my question now - why i can't see my created database?

Comment: oh, i try manually to make new dataConnection and found created database in list, so now all it's ok. But I have one more question Do i always must to manually add dataConnection for just created data base or it's can be added automatically?

Comment: @Kirill unfortunately you should add connection manually. Even with Sql Server Management Studio you should refresh database list to see new database arrived