# Server Error in '/' Application (model backing up the ApplicationDbContext)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I dont know how to get rid off this error..on line 24

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

```
Line 22:         public ViewResult Index()
Line 23:         {
Line 24:             var customers = _context.Customers.Include(c => c.MembershipType).ToList();
Line 25: 
Line 26:             return View(customers);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408608/the-model-backing-the-applicationdbcontext-context-has-changed-since-the-datab)

Comment: Have you used _Code First Migrations to update the database_?

Comment: No it didn't solve my error