# How to sort DbSet while preserving async-ness?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

The DBContext with DBSet object:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{

       public TestContext() : base("name=TestContext")
    {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/a/6143116/2404470
        Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(null);
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<UI.Models.Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

Using entity framework, I can select all data from database table like this:

```
db.Tests.ToListAsync()
```

I need data sorted based on column A and B while preserving async-ness. How can I achieve that?

Comment: since you are using async, you can't use `ToListAsync().OrderBy(..)' you can sort it after the `toList` is over again usng the `OrderBy(..)` fucntion

Comment: Hello @LiranBo - so I can do `db.Conferences.ToList().OrderBy(t=>t.A).OrderBy(t=>t.B)`. How do I preserve the **async-ness**?

Comment: `db.Conferences.ToList().OrderBy(t=>t.A)` this should work. 
this `db.Conferences.ToList().OrderBy(t=>t.A).OrderBy(t=>t.B)` will be the same as `db.Conferences.ToList().OrderBy(t=>t.B)`
you should try : `db.Conferences.ToList().OrderBy(t=>t.A).ThenBy(t=>t.B)`

Comment: This was an eye opener for me! :) Still, how do I keep async-ness? I do not see a method returning `awaiter` here

Comment: well, only partially. { A =1, B =2} { A=2, B =1}  ==(first orderby) ==> { A =1, B =2} { A=2, B =1} ==(2nd orderby)==>  { A=2, B =1} { A =1, B =2}

Comment: Hi. `var tests = await db.Tests.ToListAsync(); tests.OrderBy(t=>t.A).OrderBy(t=>t.B)`

Comment: maybe you can check [this](https://github.com/Doxense/foundationdb-dotnet-client/issues/44)

Think about the logic here, you want to sort something before you have all the elements. I'm not saying it's impossible but it requires some effort

Comment: Thanks LiranBo. Looks interesting. MikeVitik - the solution doesn't seems to be working.