# ASP.NET MVC insert into auto increment id returns zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

when i submit, i cant insert the data to database.

i used breakpoint and it seems my auto icrement id returns zero.

this is my model

```
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
```

[image: insert into debug]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you cannot get the auto-increment ID to come back is because your context (database) is different from your model layer (or, at least, EntityFramework/Code-First thinks it is).  If you are using code-first, try the following in the nuget package command console:

```
update-database
```

Or, try:

```
update-database -force
```

See this article for more info [The model backing the <Database> context has changed since the database was created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600175/the-model-backing-the-database-context-has-changed-since-the-database-was-crea)

See the following as a reference of the various code-first commands https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/

> **Update-Database**
>
> Applies any pending migrations to the database.
>
> *-Force*
>
> Specifies that data loss is acceptable during automatic migration of the database.