# Can we mix new table and existing view in EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I created some classes and a table in db for those classes with migration. I tested my code by adding some data to the classes,saved by EF and saw the data saved properly in db.

Later when I created a view in db and maped that view in code the problems started. When I tried to query this way:

```
 using (var db = new TestDBContext())
    {
        var listMyViews = db.vwCustomer.ToList();
    }
```

I was getting an error message like

**Additional information: The model backing the 'TestDBContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database**

So EF is telling me to migrate features to create view in db but view exists already. So why do I need to recreate it by migration?

### my full code with view mapping and class

```
public class CustomerBase
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }

}

public class Customer : CustomerBase
{
    public virtual List<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Addresses
{
    [Key]
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Contacts
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public virtual Addresses Customer { get; set; } 

}

public class vwCustomer
        {
            public int CustomerID { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

        }

public class TestDBContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDBContext()
        : base("name=TestDBContext")
    {
    }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new vwCustomerConfiguration());
        }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<vwCustomer> vwCustomer { get; set; }
}

public class vwCustomerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<vwCustomer>
{
    public vwCustomerConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.CustomerID);
        this.ToTable("vwCustomer");
    }
}
```

Later I tried to see if any migration is pending **issuing Add-Migration "My_vwCustomer".** I saw new migration code being added as below. It seems there is no migration pending.

```
public partial class My_vwCustomer : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.vwCustomers",
                c => new
                    {
                        CustomerID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        FirstName = c.String(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.CustomerID);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropTable("dbo.vwCustomers");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way we can do it and it solve my problem. see the code.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

code taken from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6143116/6188148

**we can follow this approach too.**

```
public partial class AddingvwCustomer : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
```

i guess this will works too but not tested myself.

**we can use the Fluent API to configure it using the Ignore method:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Ignore<MyClass>();
}
```

thanks