# Reusing old DbContext class name seems to use old class's model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm having a problem where it seems that EF is remembering the database model for a `DbContext` class that I deleted. Here is a summary of what happened (all `DbContexts` made with the "Code First from database" wizard):

1. Create  DbContext, name it `MyDbContext`
2. Use `MyDbContext`, works fine, eventually decide to restructure
3. Delete the `MyDbContext` file
4. Create a new DbContext, name it `DifferentDbContext`
5. Use `DifferentDbContext`, works fine
6. Rename `DifferentDbContext` to `MyDbContext`

Now, it starts throwing the

> "The model backing the '`MyDbContext`' context has changed..."

Exception. Renaming it back to `DifferentDbContext` (or any new name) makes it works fine again.

What I have tried:

- Clean project/solution
- Uninstall EF, clean project, reinstall EF
- Restart Visual Studio/computer
- Search solution and file system for usage of `MyDbContext`
- Ensured connection strings are correct

My best guess is that there could be some old auto-generated EF code/cache, but I haven't managed to find anything. Has anyone else seen something like this or have an idea of what could be causing it?

Comment: You may find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600175/the-model-backing-the-database-context-has-changed-since-the-database-was-crea

Comment: Thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/a/43428637/2525568 fixed the issue, but I'm still not sure why it was still looking for these old tables in the first place.