# context has changed since the database was created

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting this error when I run my MVC3 application:

> The model backing the 'MoviesDB' context has changed since the database was created. Either manually delete/update the database, or call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance. For example, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it with new data.

I am using EF 4.1. Please suggest solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code Only error: the model backing the context has changed since the database was created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552000/entity-framework-code-only-error-the-model-backing-the-context-has-changed-sinc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you added an entry in the either in the Movie model or in the database. Make sure that the schema matches and delete the EdmMetadata table.