# MVC4 & SQL 2012 Application Issue (Model Context)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, dbcontext

I have tried to create a simple app, 3 tables in 1 database created using SQL 2012. In VS2012, MVC4, created a model based off this database and then generated a controller for each table to create CRUD pages for them. After going through and changing the column labels in each View I now get this error when try to load each View:

"The model backing the 'UsersContext' context has changed since the database was created."

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
        return View(db.PCs.ToList());
 }
```

This code snipped gives the error (PCs, Servers and Terminals for their respective tables)

It tells me to use Code First Migrations, but the tutorial doesn't apply to MVC so i'm lost. I'm not even sure if doing this will even help?

Any pointers please? It's the only thing getting in the way of this app being finished!

Edit: Turns out that changing the labels for the column headings caused the issues, although I now don't know how to change the column heading without breaking it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 4.1 The model backing the context has changed since the database was created, immediately after creating DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931295/entity-framework-4-1-the-model-backing-the-context-has-changed-since-the-databas)

Comment: Not quite, it doesn't seem to apply to MVC.