# An issue created due to experimentally selecting wrong scaffolding option in EF5 , MVC4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am using VS2012 and EF5 first time. I developed application just like MVC3 , EF4.1 application without using any new feature. I already have a database , i created db context 
, models , controllers and views. Every thing was working fine. Then i created a new table Directorate in database , created its model and database mapping in dbcontext.
While creating its controller i selected "**MVC controller with read/write actions using Entity Framework**" just as an experience to see what will happen. I selected my context
and model. When i run the app it created a new table in db with the name DirectorateModel and also inserted mapping in context. As i already have created table and mapping so i deleted each new functionalities added due to this action i.e. i deleted table, context mapping , controller and views.

but now when i run the application then it gives error:

> The model backing the **'ArchievingDBContext'** context has changed
>   since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations
>   to update the database
>   (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)

I visited the mentioned url but it is about code first migrations that i don't want to use. Anyone please help me how i can fix this issue, i think i hagve to delete something 
that was created due to selection of wrong scafolding option.

I just want my application to run in previously working state.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set correct database initilizer:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContextType>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists())
```

and this work

Comment: where i have to write this? and i don't want to create database because i already have.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by calling:

> Database.SetInitializer(null);

in the Application_Start method of Global.asax

You don't want to be initializing on top of an existing database like that.

See: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552000/entity-framework-code-only-error-the-model-backing-the-context-has-changed-sinc)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Directorate entity from your .EDMX model and the controller/views you've created using scaffolding on it.

Change your database as you want and then go to the VS Model designer (just open your .EDMX model) and `Update model from database` and save changes.

Now you can add views/controllers by scaffolding without any concern...