# Modeling an existing database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to generate a model based on an existing database -- I thought it would be as simple as writing the model, adding a DbContext class, and configuring a connection string:

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class Account
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class AccountDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

With a simple boilerplate controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Accounts.ToList());
}
```

The boilerplate view, which I won't post here, which lists all of the members of the db object that we return.

ANd finally, a connection string:

```
<add name="AccountDBContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="[server connection string]" />
```

Only problem is I don't see any entries being displayed. It's definitely connecting, but not retrieving or displaying the data that the particular DB contains.. am I missing something?

**Edit**

Ok, so first thing is first: it wasn't connecting. I had a typo in my connection string name. It was hitting the default, and subsequently displaying nothing.

What I am getting now, though, is `The model backing the 'AccountDBContext' context has changed since the database was created.`

Is this because my model doesn't match exactly to what the database contains?

Comment: I think I understand, but have to ask. Seems as though you're mirroring an existing table by writing your own POCO. If I'm right, why not import from DB?

Comment: Cause it's adding a lot of extra stuff that I'm not totally sure I want looming around the project. I thought that maybe I could just manually model it and be done with it, but hitting this wall.

Comment: OIC. Yes it does. that stuff is hideous. I add a POCO code generator. Helps a lot. then I get relatively clean objects. Don't go the way of mirroring your db. you get all the head-aches of Code-First with none of the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

This is the "Code First with an Existing Database" scenario.
What version of EF are you using?

In EF 4.3 when you let code first create a database for you, it inserts a Migration-History table into the new database. It’s hidden in System Tables.This is equivalent to the EdmMetadata table you got with EF 4.1 & 4.2. But when you **already have** the database you can use **code first migrations**. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621)

Either way you should probably check if such a table exist. If it does you can delete it and then you'll be solely responsible to correctly matching your pocos to the database.

Another quick workaround i have found is putting

```
    Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
```

to your Application_Start() in Global.asax

See also this similar question: [Entity Framework Code Only error: the model backing the context has changed since the database was created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552000/entity-framework-code-only-error-the-model-backing-the-context-has-changed-sinc)