# The model backing the 'myDBContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I made some changes to Entity and I successfully executed "update-database -verbose" in packageManager console and I can see changes reflected in the azure database .

Then I did a deployment to azure cloud and I am getting the Error message from Azure cloud

```
"The model backing the 'myDBContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database"
```

I tried setting Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false and a re-deployment

But still I am getting same error .

Please help ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code Only error: the model backing the context has changed since the database was created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552000/entity-framework-code-only-error-the-model-backing-the-context-has-changed-sinc)

Answer (score 8):

I resolved this issue by adding

`Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);`  to Application_Start()  inside Global.asax.cs